# How to declare and initialize a List?

Tags: java, list

I need to make array or list of a class.

My class

```
public class TreeItem {
 private int key;//tankstation Id
 private String regio;
 private String gemeente;//tankstation naam
 private String brandstof;
 private String tankInhoud;
 private String maxTankInhoud;
 private String minWaarde;
 private String drempelWaarde;
 ....
 }
```

In C# you could make a list just by

```
List<TreeItem> list = new List<TreeItem>();
```

How do you do this in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need an ArrayList

```
List<TreeItem> list = new ArrayList<TreeItem>();
```

LinkedList

```
List<TreeItem> list = new LinkedList<TreeItem>();
```